# Should I inherit from User model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two other models that should have all the functionalities that User model have. That's why in those two models, I am inheriting from User model.

```
default_role = "admin"

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
   ...
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path, blank=True, null=True)
   role = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ROLE_CHOICE, default=default_role)
   ....

class Student(User):
   ...
   some_fields_related_to_student
   ...
   def save():
      self.role = "student"

class Teacher(User):
   ...
   some_fields_related_to_teacher
   ...
   def save():
       self.role = "teacher"
```

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename, role):
    extension = filename.split('.')[-1]
    return f"{role}/{instance.id}.{extension}"
```

When I try to put the image pictures for Teacher and Student models, I want to put them in:

```
".../teachers/{teacher.id}.{extension}" 
".../students/{student.id}.{extension}" these folders.
```

How can I pass the role field to **user_directory_path** function or what is the best practice in this situation? Is it a correct way to put images in the folders related to their models?

Also, my other question is; should I inherit from User at all?
Whenever I create Student or Teacher, it is also creating that model in User too, but for me it looks like not optimal, since we are kinda duplicating the information

Answer (score 1):

This approach may lead to several issues for your projects later, such as:

1. Authentication Complexity
2. Complexity in Forms and Views
3. Role Changing
4. Adding Unnecessary and Unwanted Joins to All SQL Queries

To address these concerns, let's explore some best practices:

> If you’re starting a new project, it’s highly recommended to set up a
> custom user model, even if the default User model is sufficient for
> you. This model behaves identically to the default user model, but
> you’ll be able to customize it in the future if the need arises.
> [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project)

2.2 Profile Model:

For handling different user roles, consider using a profile model. You can create separate profile classes for each role and link them to the user model using a OneToOneField. This approach reduces code duplication and provides better control over database joins with `select_related`. Here's an example implementation:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    # Common fields and methods here

class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Teacher-specific fields here

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Student-specific fields here

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Employee-specific fields here
```

Additionally, if you're concerned about separate picture folders for Teacher and Student models, you can use the upload_to attribute and customize storage.

```py
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # Determine the user's role
    role = "other"
    if hasattr(instance, 'teacher'):
        role = 'teacher'
    elif hasattr(instance, 'student'):
        role = 'student'
    elif hasattr(instance, 'employee'):
        role = 'employee'

    # Create a directory structure based on the user's role
    return f"user_{instance.user.id}/{role}/{filename}"

class User(AbstractUser):
    # Common fields and methods here
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

Another option is to use FileSystemStorage for even more customization.

```py
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

class UserRoleStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def get_user_role(self, instance):
       # Determine the user's role here

    def _save(self, name, content):
        # Get the user's role
        user_role = self.get_user_role(self.instance)

        # Construct the dynamic upload path
        path = f"user_{self.instance.user.id}/{user_role}/{name}"

        # Call the parent class to save the file
        return super()._save(path, content)

class User(models.Model):
    upload = models.FileField(storage=UserRoleStorage())
```

2.3 Using JSONField:

Another approach is to use a JSONField for profile data. It's straightforward on the model side but can be challenging when dealing with views, permissions, and validation. Here's an example:

```py
class RoleType(models.IntegerChoices):
    Student = 1

def get_default_dynamic_field_definitions():
    return {}

class User(models.Model):
    data = models.JSONField(default=get_default_dynamic_field_definitions)
    role = models.IntegerField(choices=RoleType.choices)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Update self.data here
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

2.4 Dynamic Profile Field Builder Pattern:

For a more complex but flexible solution, consider using a dynamic profile field builder pattern. This approach allows you to define fields in your views. Here's a basic example:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
class DynamicField(models.Model):
    STANDARD_FIELD_TYPES = (
        (models.CharField, 'Text'),
        (models.EmailField, 'Email'),
        (models.IntegerField, 'Integer'),
        (models.DateField, 'Date'),
        # Add more standard field types as needed
    )

    f_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Field Name")
    f_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STANDARD_FIELD_TYPES, help_text="Field Type")
    f_validator = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, help_text="Field Validator (optional)")
    f_default = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, help_text="Field Default Value (optional)")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='dynamic_fields')


dynamic_fields = DynamicField.objects.filter(user=user_instance)
```

2.5 Model Proxy:
You can also explore the model proxy feature to extend existing model methods without changing their behaviour.

```py
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
        # Your common fields and methods here

class Teacher(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def do_something(self):
        # ...
        pass


class Student(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def do_something(self):
        # ...
        pass
```